# How to find out if this preprocessor macro exists?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to know how to find out if the preprocessor macro `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` can be used with a given compiler (As it is supposed to be non-standard). How do I check this in a header file? What I want to do is something like:

```
#ifndef __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
   #define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __func__
#endif
```

But, I'm guessing what happens is the preprocessor defines the macro in place for each function so I wonder whether there's any meaning to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (Unlike `__FILE__` or `__LINE__`) outside a function. Is this true or can I just use the code above? If not, how do I check for it?

EDIT: I tried it. `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is undefined outside a function (I didn't check inside a class). So there has to be another way.

EDIT2: Actually a simple hack would be to do this :):

```
void Dummy()
{
    #ifndef __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
       #define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __func__
    #endif
}
```

The other method is to check for compiler as was suggested by others.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not very clear ...

"I want to know how to find out if the preprocessor macro __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ can be used with a given compiler" ... and validly named preprocessor macro can be used with any compiler. 

Do you mean to ask if it is built in and defined by default for a given compiler? if so, teh you are correct with `#IFDEF`

I really don't understand what you mean by "the preprocessor defines the macro in place for each function" - can you repharse it & we can try to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to know which compiler you're using.  For GCC (the GNU Compiler Collection), you'd probably test:

```
#ifdef __GNUG__
...use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#endif
```

You might check the compiler version if you know which one introduced the feature and you are in any danger of having your code compiled with an older version.

### The GCC (4.4.1) manual says:

> In C, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is yet another name for `__func__`. However, in C++, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains the type signature of the function as well as its bare name.
>   For example, this program:
>
> ```
>  extern "C" {
>      extern int printf (char *, ...);
>  }
>  class a {
>  public:
>      void sub (int i)
>      {
>          printf ("__FUNCTION__ = %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
>          printf ("__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
>      }
>  };
>  int
>  main (void)
>  {
>      a ax;
>      ax.sub (0);
>      return 0;
>  }
> ```
>
> gives this output:
>
> ```
>  __FUNCTION__ = sub
>  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = void a::sub(int)
> ```
>
> These identifiers are not preprocessor macros. In GCC 3.3 and earlier, in C only, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string literals; they could be used
>   to initialize char arrays, and they could be concatenated with other string literals. GCC
>   3.4 and later treat them as variables, like `__func__`. In C++, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_
>   FUNCTION__` have always been variables.